# Design Pattern for accounting hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns

I am creating a accounting hierarchy for the financial domain of an application. My requirement is to create an accounting hierarchy for some object. I need to ensure that the code I will write should be generic so that it can be used with other objects. Should I need to use some design pattern for it or just one java class. I need some suggestions.

Thank you.
Ravi

Comment: Question is very generic. You need to study up design patterns more. You have some good advice below, but I wonder if you will be able to articulate it until you study design patterns in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view... when I hear `account`, I think **State**.

look here, why:

[image]

(This picture belongs to http://www.bnsit.pl/)

Of course you can use your own implementing classes and interface, that will fit your needs. But the idea is still the same - there's one interface that represents whole account classes, and there are *some* implementations, that **allows you do or do not** implemented methods, accordingly to the state of given account.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [analysis patterns (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accounting.pdf) that can apply to an accounting system.

*Accounts* tie *Parties* with *Accounting Entries*, which originate from *Accounting Transactions* that can be created from *Posting Rules*. *Accounts* can be connected to other accounts with schemes such as *Derived Account* or *Summary Account*. An *Accounting Practice* encapsulates the rules in effect in a defined context.

Take a look at the following books: Analysis Patterns (Martin Fowler) and Domain Driven Design (Eric Evans).